# BIOS and DOS interrupts (16H and 21H)

Tags: assembly, bios, keyboardinterrupt

There are some routines which can be implemented via both `INT 21H` and `INT 16H` (former is for DOS and latter is for BIOS). However, the exact difference is not clear (at least for me!).

For example, the following routines read a character from keyboard

1) `INT 21H`, service 01 for reading with echo

```
MOV   AH,01
INT   21H
```

2) `INT 16H`, service 01 for key press

```
MOV   AH,01
INT   16H
```

Assume a program which is waiting for a key. For example, a simple text based wizard which waits for Y/N. For echoing the pressed key, which one is preferred? 21H or 16H.

I can think that BIOS routines should be called when there is no operating system (example is "press F1 to continue" during POST). Is that all? Is there any example, that shows an operation is exclusively done by one of them and not both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For echoing the pressed key, which one is preferred? 21H or 16H.

Certainly **not** the BIOS function since it will not echo anything!

> INT 16H, service 01 for key press

This function will only check if a key is available. It will not remove it from the keyboard buffer.

In general you need to be aware that DOS input functions can use re-direction. The input might not come from the keyboard at all. It could come from a file or other source.

Comment: As you said, INT 16H only checks if a key is pressed. As I said, that is also possible with INT 21H. Don't you agree?

Comment: From your answer, I understand that INT 21H will remove the key from buffer. Is that correct? Regarding INT 16H, why should a key be present in a buffer after checking its availability?

Comment: BIOS function 01h allows you to preview the content of the keyboard buffer. BIOS function 00h will effectively remove the key from the same buffer.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask another question. When it is possible to use both DOS and BIOS functions for a routine, which one is preferred?

Comment: There's no clear answer to this question. You would have to closely look at the tiny differences that there surely are! I myself prefer to use BIOS over DOS. Routines that don't depend on DOS are much more easily ported to an operating-system-less environment.